# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googletrans' although I installed it correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, google-translate, modulenotfounderror

I'm trying to import a googletrans package but I got a ModuleNotFoundError when I'm trying to import it although I installed it.

I got this error

```
11 #to translate the text data
12 get_ipython().system('pip install googletrans')
---> 13 from googletrans import Translator

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googletrans'
```

I'm trying to install a **googletrans** package with all possible syntax on jupyter notebook

```
!pip install googletrans
!pip install googletrans==4.0.0-rc1 #to avoid 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' error
!pip install googletrans==3.1.0a0 #to avoid 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' error
```

after I'm installing it, I'm trying to import it

`from googletrans import Translator`

I got this error

```
11 #to translate the text data
12 get_ipython().system('pip install googletrans')
13 from googletrans import Translator

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googletrans'
```

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googletrans'**

but I have to notify you that the output from pip command is

```
Collecting googletrans
  Using cached googletrans-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting httpx==0.13.3
  Using cached httpx-0.13.3-py3-none-any.whl (55 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\python310\lib\site-packages (from httpx==0.13.3->googletrans) (2021.10.8)
Collecting hstspreload
  Using cached hstspreload-2021.12.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.3 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: sniffio in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\python310\lib\site-packages (from httpx==0.13.3->googletrans) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: rfc3986<2,>=1.3 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\python310\lib\site-packages (from httpx==0.13.3->googletrans) (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet==3.* in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\python310\lib\site-packages (from httpx==0.13.3->googletrans) (3.0.4)
Collecting httpcore==0.9.*
  Using cached httpcore-0.9.1-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
Collecting idna==2.*
  Using cached idna-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
Collecting h2==3.*
  Using cached h2-3.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (65 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: h11<0.10,>=0.8 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\python310\lib\site-packages (from httpcore==0.9.*->httpx==0.13.3->googletrans) (0.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: hpack<4,>=3.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\python310\lib\site-packages (from h2==3.*->httpcore==0.9.*->httpx==0.13.3->googletrans) (3.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: hyperframe<6,>=5.2.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\python310\lib\site-packages (from h2==3.*->httpcore==0.9.*->httpx==0.13.3->googletrans) (5.2.0)
Installing collected packages: idna, hstspreload, h2, httpcore, httpx, googletrans
  Attempting uninstall: idna
    Found existing installation: idna 3.3
    Uninstalling idna-3.3:
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -na (c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -2na (c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -1na (c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -na (c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -0na (c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -dna (c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -na (c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -2na (c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -1na (c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -na (c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -0na (c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -dna (c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -na (c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -2na (c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -1na (c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -na (c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -0na (c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -dna (c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\python310\lib\site-packages)
    WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -na (c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\python310\lib\site-packages)
    WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -2na (c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\python310\lib\site-packages)
    WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -1na (c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\python310\lib\site-packages)
    WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -na (c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\python310\lib\site-packages)
...
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -na (c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -0na (c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -dna (c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\python310\lib\site-packages
```

It's installed with these warnings.

What's the wrong here? is it with the installation or with the import syntax and how I can solve it.

note: I'm using anaconda with 3.9.7 and 3.10

Comment: Please use current best practices when installing in a notebook cell. You should be using `%pip install <package>` or `%conda install <package>`. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about that. The exclamation point can sometimes lead you to install in the wrong location. The modern magics was added to avoid this. Often because automagics is turned on by default, no symbol in front of `pip` or `conda` will often work as it tries to use the magics command version when no symbol is provided.

Comment: The one reason might be your environment,  if you are using virtual environment, then package must installed in virtual environment. Cross check once, if installed package is without virtual environment but anaconda run in virtual environment or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I see in your logs that you are using Anaconda. To install this package with conda run one of the following:

```
conda install -c conda-forge googletrans

conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 googletrans

conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 googletrans
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this code run through anaconda or external? If you are using external run, open spyder with anaconda and try again.

If you need to external run, you must be install `pip install googletrans` in cmd.exe and add python to path.

How can I add python to path?: https://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-do-i-add-python-to-the-windows-path

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. My fix was to make sure my system was looking for the package in the right area. Googletrans had been downloaded to a local folder but my system was looking into an anaconda folder.

Run: `import sys print(sys.path)`

If the path to your downloaded googletrans does not appear, then:

```
sys.path.append("/path/to/googletrans")
```

Make sure the path is copied correctly.